# How to change sorting package/file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, package

if i create for example a new file in the layout folder/package it automatically sorts the file alphabetically and I can't drag it at the position I want.

Is there a way to change this behavior as I want every new file that is being created to be at the bottom of the package/folder like for example Xcode does by default.

Comment: What is "the layout folder/package"? Do you mean the `res/layout` directory within your source set?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes that was just an example. It happens on every folder tho

Comment: OK, I was just making sure I understood what you were referring to. AFAIK, there is no configuration option for that. Contents of directories are presented in alpha order, and there is no option for a different order or for manual sequencing.

Comment: hmm ok thanks for helping anyways @CommonsWare

Comment: Xcode has manual sorting. I wish this was also in IntellijIdea / Android Studio. It's really useful to give a meaningful sorting to the files in a package.